# Binding WPF Datagrid's row color to a property of an item inside an observable collection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, itemssource

I am hoping someone can help me with this.  I have an MVVMLight application in which I have an observable collection of objects, in my view-model, bound to the WPF DataGrid's ItemsSource property.  Now I want to change the row background color whenever a specific value called "TaskAssignmentStatus" changes for any item inside the observable collection.

*However I am getting a XAML Parse error as follows:*

**{"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."}**

I have read everything I can find regarding that error but I haven't been able to see how to apply anything I have learned from the answers given thus far to my specific situation.  I am very much a new to WPF and databiding so any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

The relevant code from my view-model is as follows:

```
//Contains the actual tasks on the currently selected team member's    
//work-list
public ObservableCollection<WorklistTask> TasksForSelectedTeamMember
{
    get { return _tasksForSelectedTeamMember; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            _tasksForSelectedTeamMember = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TasksForSelectedTeamMember");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class definition for the types inside my observable collection in the view-model:

```
public class WorklistTask : ICloneable
{
    #region Fields

    private int _taskId;
    private int _activityId;
    private string _activityName;
    private string _activityStatus;
    private string _taskAssignDate;
    private string _activityStartDate;
    private string _activityDueDate;
    private string _caseStartDate;
    private string _caseDueDate;
    private int _caseId;
    private string _caseType;

    //an enum which indicates whether or not the task has been reassigned 
    private WorkListTaskAssignmentStatus _taskAssignmentStatus;

    private int _sourceTaskId;
    private bool _selectedByUserInUI = false;


    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public WorklistTask() { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [DisplayName("Task Assignment Status")]
    public WorkListTaskAssignmentStatus TaskAssignmentStatus
    {
        get { return _taskAssignmentStatus; }
        set { _taskAssignmentStatus = value; }
    }


    public int TaskId
    {
        get { return _taskId; }
        set { _taskId = value; }
    }


    public int ActivityId
    {
        get { return _activityId; }
        set { _activityId = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName("Activity Name")]
    public string ActivityName
    {
        get { return _activityName; }
        set { _activityName = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Activity Status")]
    public string ActivityStatus
    {
        get { return _activityStatus; }
        set { _activityStatus = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Task Assigned Date")]
    public string TaskAssignDate
    {
        get { return _taskAssignDate; }
        set { _taskAssignDate = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Activity Start Date")]
    public string ActivityStartDate
    {
        get { return _activityStartDate; }
        set { _activityStartDate = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Activity Due Date")]
    public string ActivityDueDate
    {
        get { return _activityDueDate; }
        set { _activityDueDate = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Case Start Date")]
    public string CaseStartDate
    {
        get { return _caseStartDate; }
        set { _caseStartDate = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Case Due Date")]
    public string CaseDueDate
    {
        get { return _caseDueDate; }
        set { _caseDueDate = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName("Case Id")]
    public int CaseId
    {
        get { return _caseId; }
        set { _caseId = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Case Type")]
    public string CaseType
    {
        get { return _caseType; }
        set { _caseType = value; }
    }


    public int SourceTaskId
    {
        get { return _sourceTaskId; }
        set { _sourceTaskId = value; }
    }

    public bool SelectedByUserInUI
    {
        get { return _selectedByUserInUI; }
        set { _selectedByUserInUI = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public object Clone()
    {
        WorklistTask newWorklistTask = (WorklistTask)this.MemberwiseClone();
        newWorklistTask.ActivityName = string.Copy(ActivityName);
        newWorklistTask.ActivityStatus = string.Copy(ActivityStatus);
        newWorklistTask.TaskAssignDate = string.Copy(TaskAssignDate);
        newWorklistTask.ActivityStartDate = string.Copy(ActivityStartDate);
        newWorklistTask.ActivityDueDate = string.Copy(ActivityDueDate);
        newWorklistTask.CaseStartDate = string.Copy(CaseStartDate);
        newWorklistTask.CaseDueDate = string.Copy(CaseDueDate);
        newWorklistTask.CaseType = string.Copy(CaseType);

        return newWorklistTask;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the enum:

```
public enum WorkListTaskAssignmentStatus
{
    Automatic,
    Added,
    Removed,
    DeleteLocal
}
```

Here is the XAML for the datagrid I am trying to format:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WorklistOfSelectedTeamMember"
          ItemsSource="{Binding TasksForSelectedTeamMember, Mode=TwoWay,   
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                 
          AutoGeneratingColumn="GenerateColumnsForWorklist"                                   
          IsReadOnly="True"
          FontWeight="Normal"
          FontSize="13" 
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Grid.Row="3" 
          Margin="0,0,5,0"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          Height="150"
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridColoring}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding 
                WorklistTaskSelectionChangedCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, 
                ElementName=WorklistOfSelectedTeamMember}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="Automatic">  
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="Removed">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C4FF0000"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="Added">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF7F"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="DeleteLocal">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FFFFFF"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>                            
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the error you are getting by adding the implicit RowStyle to the **Resources** dictionary of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WorklistOfSelectedTeamMember"
          ItemsSource="{Binding TasksForSelectedTeamMember, Mode=TwoWay,   
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                   
          IsReadOnly="True"
          FontWeight="Normal"
          FontSize="13" 
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Grid.Row="3" 
          Margin="0,0,5,0"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          Height="150">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding 
                WorklistTaskSelectionChangedCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, 
                ElementName=WorklistOfSelectedTeamMember}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="Automatic">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="Removed">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C4FF0000"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="Added">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF7F"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskAssignmentStatus}" 
                 Value="DeleteLocal">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FFFFFF"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Also note that if you want the background colour of the row to change when you set the value of the TaskAssignmentStatus property of an item in your ObservableCollection to a new value dynamically at runtime, the WorklistTask class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the TaskAssignmentStatus property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  This was what I needed to resolve the issue so I am very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Your code to change background color seems just fine and it should work.

The error string you mention isn't about that, it means that you're trying somehow to add/remove elements directly from the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid `DataGrid.ItemsSource`

You can't use ItemsSource to directly modify your elements you must use the collection instead.

Comment: Thanks Poncianux, I appreciate your insights.  I did double check what you mentioned might be the issue just to be sure.  So thanks for your assistance!